# How to create circular icons for favorites function in Android contact app?

Tags: java, android

I am looking for a way to implement a circular thumbnail view for users to select their favorites from a list of contacts. Could that be done using a custom list view? I also want to be able to create a context menu when the user long presses the thumbnail. Would be grand if anyone knows of any open sourced resources to such an implementation as well, if not a pseudo example of how to implement would be fine as well. Thank you!

Because I can't post images, here is an [image: example]
<sub>(source: [indianexpress.com](http://images.indianexpress.com/2015/11/contactp-main.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class RoundedImageView which will extends ImageView then customize it.Here is code below for RoundedImageView. Then use it as a view in your xml

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public ChimmerRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float radius = 90.0f; // angle of round corners
        Path clipPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
}
```

And add this property in aplication tag in android Manifest.

```
<application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use external libraries
use this [Circularimageview](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView) library

```
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
```

This is your image view

```
<com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAvatar
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true" />
```

Dont forget to include this schema in ur xml

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.pkmmte.view"
```

Usage

```
imgAvatar = (CircularImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
imgAvatar.setImageResource(your image here);
```